# How to get string of specific width for GDI+?

Tags: c#, gdi+

If i have a string and i want to get part of a string of specific width how can i get that?
Suppose my

```
string MyStringIs="MyBasketItems1, MyBasketItems1, MyBasketItems1, "\n"MyBasketItems4";
```

I want to get a part of this string of specific width to draw on a panel how can i get that?

Comment: That's cool but as @KonradRudolph has already explained a draw back with long length string, if he could explain how to achieve this with binary search that could be of great avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this function (barely tested)

```
public string GetMaxPixelSubstring(string input, int maxLength, Graphics graph, Font font)
{
     string part = "";
     foreach (char oneChar in input.ToCharArray())
     {
        string temp = part + oneChar;

        if (graph.MeasureString(temp, font).Width > maxLength) 
           return part;
        else
           part = temp;
     }
     return input;
}
```

The idea is looping on the original input string character by character, adding them to a partial string and measuring the partial string lenght in pixel using a specific font.

For example, calling the above function inside a form button click event

```
string MyStringIs="MyBasketItems1, MyBasketItems1, MyBasketItems1, MyBasketItems4";
string result = GetSubstrings(MyStringIs, 220, this.CreateGraphics(), new Font("Arial", 12f));
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Display "MyBasketItems1, MyBasketIt"

Comment: Your example code leaks resources – do not use. But yeah, the basic idea is sound.

Comment: Here max length is pre known max string length that can be drawn..?

Comment: +1 Almost certainly good enough. But I imagine a binary search would be slightly better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you explain the leak, I can't grasp it

Comment: @Steve Both `Graphics` and `Font` are unmanaged resources and implement `IDisposable`. This means that you need to manually dispose them, otherwise you leak GDI+ handles. Failure to do so can lead to an exhaustion of handles and subsequent graphics errors (earlier versions of Visual Studio had this problem).

Comment: @ta.speot.is: what do you mean by binary search?

Comment: @Steve Could you describe  int maxLength in your example please...i know width of my panel that i need to pass here.?

Comment: @KonradRudolph ah yes I see your point, I suppose then that this code should be called in a Paint event and use the Graphics and the font of the panel then. You are right but that was just to test the function

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet Imagine if you had a 10,000 character string and 100,000 pixels. This solution would take quite a while. Instead, start with the full length of the string. If it doesn't fit, cut it in two. If it doesn't fit, cut it in two. If it does fit, try adding half of what was previously cut to it etc.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet yes and check the comment from Konrad Rudolph

Comment: @KonradRudolph that is the problem, how would i know if string fit or not, i want to know how can i check this? ..the function really may take a long time, if my basket items are more..